# Executar uma ação automaticamente ao abrir app

Tags: java, android

estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de um app e estou com uma duvida, preciso que meu app execute uma ação ao abrir o mesmo. Alguem sabe me dizer como posso fazer isso? Ja procurei e não acho nada a respeito.

Comment: Não é só jogar o código dentro do `oncreate`? chega a dar algum erro?

Comment: É então foi o que eu fiz, mais não obtive sucesso. Ele não da nenhum erro apenas não mostra o resultado.

Comment: O que estou fazendo é pegar um calculo feito em uma activity e fazer ele aparecer na activity principal em um textView.

Comment: Precisa [edit] a pergunta  e adicionar mais detalhes, não sei exatamente o quer que o código faça.

Comment: Sim irei fazer isso que não estou com o codigo no momento chegando em casa irei editar aqui, obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Pesquise sobre a LifeCycle de um app, de uma olhada no link abaixo e veja se atende sua necessidade. [Entendendo o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação Android](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922)

Comment: pelo que você comentou, provavelmente é porque a segunda activity não foi iniciada, então não há valor a ser passado pra activity principal. Mas só poderemos saber com o código e o log de erro

Comment: chegando colocarei o codigo e dou um toque aqui mais obrigado por enquanto